# Does outlook permit searching in email headers?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

I just noticed there is a specific header I would like to be able to search for. Is it possible to set up search on the basis of headers in Outlook 360? I see I can create a filter for a header, but is there a way to search without first creating a filter?

Comment: Not using OWA currently but [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/763738/) might help until you get an answer.